# How to add a rear bench seat to a Chevy Express cargo van?

Tags: seat, seat-belt, express-van

I have a 2003 Chevy Express cargo van (3500 long wheel base) that I need to add a rear bench seat to. This van is replacing an older *passenger* van of the same type that is currently being used for work purposes (the old van has over half a million km and is ready for the junk yard: no reverse gear [that's fun, let me tell you], leaks a litre of oil every 4-5 days, frame is rusted out to the point where it might be unsafe to lift it on a vehicle hoist, etc.). We need to transport up to five people at times, which is why we need the bench.

We have four benches with seatbelts that we can use from the old van. Is there a way we can remove one set of brackets from the old van and install them in the new one? We have a MIG welder and a vehicle hoist for underside access, just wondering if the floor needs extra reinforcement or if we will even be able to cut out the old brackets. The seat also needs to be removable.

I haven't investigated the seatbelts yet (just got the van the other day), but I don't believe they will pose a problem, since they should be mostly interchangeable.

Has anybody done this before? I've been searching but haven't found anything about putting OEM seats in an Express cargo van.

Comment: You should be able to add them, but you'll want to re-enforce all areas where you are going to be mounting seat or seat belt. The thin sheet metal is strong, no doubt, but when you mount up the seat and the belts, this puts a lot of stress into one area. You'll want to get some type of rail or strips of metal to most likely provide support from underneath the vehicle. This, IMHO, would provide you the most support for your needs. Safety should be your first and foremost concern. This is not authoritative, so am leaving it as a comment.

Comment: I believe the seat belt is attached to the vertical frame, not sheet metal. I don't see why the passenger van would have the mounting holes and the cargo van wouldn't, so it will probably just be a matter of swapping it out. I'm more concerned about the floor brackets.

Comment: Hmm... further searching brought up [this](http://forums.edmunds.com/discussion/16128/chevrolet/express/chevy-express-gmc-savana-accessories-modifications) page, which had a lot of valuable information. It seems that the seatbelts are indeed easily bolted in, and the floor brackets are "rails" that are simply bolted to the frame directly beneath the floor (holed need to be drilled, of course, but no supports need to be added).

Comment: You may want to check with your local Department  of Motor Vehicles and your insurance company to reclassify your van for 5 passengers. They may choose not to cover the passengers in the event of an accident.

Comment: @mikes: That won't be an issue. These vans are rated for 15 passengers. Especially since it's OEM brackets, seats, and seatbelts we're putting in, and not some third-party stuff.

Comment: Check your vehicle registration it may state 2 passengers.

Comment: @FighterJet You should still check, as they may classify a cargo van and a minibus/passenger van differently, even if they are the same model. Certainly many insurance companies would see it as a declarable modification.

Comment: @mikes: You misunderstand. It won't be an issue for me to have the vehicle reclassified if I need to, since I'm not putting, say, seats in the bed of a pickup truck. The vans are identical in pretty much every way, except one has a few less windows, no seats, and no carpet.

Comment: This is most likely not pertinent, but I have seen one "cargo" van that still had one of the brackets hid underneath the carpet.  All that was required to add another bench was to cut a hole in the carpet and pop it in.  Of course, the belts would still be an issue to work through.

Comment: @anonymous2: This van has no carpet (the last owner put down a plywood floor), and I believe the brackets rails are surface mounted. In passenger models, the carpet is thick enough so that it is flush with the top of the bracket. But while not relevant for this van in particular, it might be helpful to others with different vehicles.